# Cannot copy the text of multiple comments at once due to CSS display:contents

Tags: bug, comments, design

Stack Exchange seems to be using the new CSS property `display:contents` in a way that interferes with copying the text of comments. (Using Firefox 58.0.2 or Chromium 64.0.3282.167 on Mint Linux)

If you highlight multiple comments, then copying them to clipboard doesn't work anymore. If I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on [this selection of text](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/157519/some-lonely-primes#comment383699_157519), then my clipboard has only a single space character in it.

[image]

If I toggle-off the `display:contents` property, then copying works normally but it explodes visually.

[image]

`display:contents` is an experimental new CSS feature

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#display-box
- https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#valdef-display-contents
- https://css-tricks.com/get-ready-for-display-contents/

I don't really understand what it is **meant** to be used for, but I don't think this text-copying-prevention is the intended purpose (either from W3C or hopefully from Stack Exchange!).

Comment: Perhaps you should add some details about the system/browser you're using? I'm not having any trouble copying and pasting multiple comments in Chrome for Windows.

Comment: You can't even copy-paste *a single comment* along with its author and date-time.

Comment: Firefox 58.0.1 can't reproduce anymore. It was a problem before.

Comment: @Draco18s Browser-version?

Comment: Note: I've added my browser/OS version to the post. (Firefox 58.0.2 or Chromium 64.0.3282.167 on Mint Linux). Thanks, Catija.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Chromium 64.0.3282.167 on Ubuntu. Strange.

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior in FF 58.0.1 for Mac El Capitan but not Chrome 64.0.3282.167.

Comment: @Braiam Firefox of some variety. Fairly new. I'll have to check later. At home I've got 50.1 and that copies just fine.

Comment: Can you explain a use case for copying multiple comments at once? I get that sometimes you may copy a piece of code from a single comment, but several complete comments at once?

Comment: @balpha If you want to print them out?

Comment: @balpha to present them on meta. Also, some people starts selecting from the time to the start of the comment (ie. I drag the pointer on your comment from the timestamp to the first word), which would trigger this bug. Oh, btw, I can reproduce it now.

Comment: @Braiam ok the browser the issue occurred on is Firefox 58.0.2 (64 bit).

Comment: @balpha The comment I tried to copy the other day was one on Space.SE about the number of times a user had seen the word "pee" in the Q&A compared with the number of times they'd seen it on SE as a whole (3 and 3). I thought it was funny and was trying to copy that question over to Discord to share, but because I had the audacity to copy *the entire comment* (including attribution) I could not. It wasn't until I copied slightly less than "everything" that I was able to.